# Java LibGDX Flip String Vertical

Tags: java, android, libgdx

**My Code:**

```
SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();
String string = "100";
batch.begin()
font.draw(batch, string, 0, 0);
batch.end();
```

**I tried this:**

```
font.draw(batch, new StringBuilder(string).reverse(), 0, 0);
```

But It results "001". I don't want to flip horizontal, I want to flip **vertical** For example:

[image: 100]

Comment: The image alone tells nothing. Be more precise about your problem and post code.

Comment: Then why don't you start by cropping your image to show only the relevant parts? From this question alone it is unclear what you want to do. Especially since there seem to be other components to your image. Also, post the code which you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `new BitmapFont(true)` to generate an upside-down font.

Or you can flip your font back and forth with `font.setScale(1, -1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you are trying is can't be achieved with text but can be achieved with image because the vertical flip of your text is not an actual text in real world.

So what you can do is create an image and you can simply scale its height by -1 to achieve the desired effect.

Hope this helps, Try something and come up with some efforts to get better response.

Answer (score 0):

You can render the text to an off-screen target, and then render that target texture with flipped coordinates. You can use a [FrameBuffer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FrameBuffer.html) for this.

Another alternative is to flip the camera itself, by setting your `SpriteBatch` projection matrix before calling `batch.begin()`

```
Matrix4 matrix = new Matrix4();
...
batch.setProjectionMatrix(matrix.set(camera.combined).scl(1, -1, 1));
batch.begin();
font.draw(batch, string, 0, 0);
batch.end();
```